# Facebook Connect always returns app to splash screen on iPad only

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, ipad

As the title suggests, I have an app which uses Facebook connect to log users in.

On the iPhone this works fine; it switches to the Facebook app, logs in and then goes back to my app at the same place it left off.

However on an iPad (I only have an iPad 1 to hand but I'm presuming the problem is across all 3), when it returns to my app it seems to have restarted it entirely. It goes back to the splash screen, and then to the login screen. The user is stuck in an endless loop of "unsuccessfully" logging in, despite the fact that the Facebook app is logging in correctly.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening on the iPad but not an iPhone?

This app is actually inherited from a much older app which was iPhone only,  and to simplify things it has essentially been left that way. The images etc are just scaled based on screen size, there is no differentiation in the code between iPhones and iPads other than their screen size. The facebook connect code has a "FBIsDeviceIPad" bool, but afaik that is just for setting the position and size of the popup login dialog when not using SSO.

Edit:
Further investigation suggests it could be an issue with OpenGL ES. The app crashes when sent to the background, as the OpenGl ES code carries on trying to animate etc. The facebook app momentarily puts my app into the background, ergo the app crashes and restarts.

I'll update this once I find out how to fix this, in the meantime if anyone has already dealt with this situation I would welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it's a memory issue as noted in the question edit. Still not resolved how to get it working, but this is at least the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppDelegate`  Class implement this code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Comment: I've already done this. As I've already mentioned, everything works correctly on the iPhone already.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the permissions that made a difference. I had the same problem om the iPhone. and i reduced the permissions and the app stopped doing that.

Comment: What do you mean by reducing the permissions ? Asking less permissions ? Ex: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends", @"user_birthday"]

Comment: @rousseauo It is an old comment, so I dont exactly remember what i did, but based on what I wrote, i think yeah. The Facebook sdk has changed a lot since, so you might want to test it out. Not sure if it will help you.